# Implement abstract function from parent class with typed arguments in PHP

Tags: php, types, overriding, abstract-class, type-hinting

I am trying to create a base class which will contain functions that all child classes must implement, but the type of the arguments will depend on the child class.

When I try the following, I get the declaration compatibility error:

```
declare(strict_types=1);

abstract class ClassA
{
    public abstract function myFunc($arg);
}

class ClassB extends ClassA
{
    public function myFunc(int $arg)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Is there any way I can achieve said functionality while abiding by the strict type policy?

Comment: `mixed $arg` ...while this defeats the whole idea of method abstraction. Not sure if generics already made it to PHP: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/generics

Comment: @matin-zeitler I tried that but still getting the error. Generics is exactly what I'm looking for but since it's not available in PHP, I'm currently looking for a workaround.